# How to print the values based on drop down selection using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Below is my code that shows movie data from the JSON variable, and displays it on the drop down list based on the selected city.

I need to show the when user select the movie in movies drop down to print the movie name and theaters list as well as theater drop down..

and select one drop down another drop down don't change(when user select the movie drop down the theater drop down is default state as well as another  )

below is my html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cityData = [
        {
            cityName: 'Bengaluru',
            value: 'Bengaluru',
            data: [
                {
                    movieName: 'ABC',
                    theaterName: 'Tulsi Theatre',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'DEF',
                    theaterName: 'PVR',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'GHI',
                    theaterName: 'Srinivasa Theatre',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            cityName: 'Hyderabad',
            value: 'Hyderabad',
            data: [
                {
                    movieName: '123',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre1',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: '456',
                    theaterName: 'PVR2',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: '789',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre3',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
            ],
        },

        {
            cityName: 'Guntur',
            value: 'Guntur',
            data: [
                {
                    movieName: 'ABC1',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre4',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'DEF2',
                    theaterName: 'PVR3',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'GHI3',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre5',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
            ],
        },

        {
            cityName: 'Ongole',
            value: 'Ongole',
            data: [],
        },
    ];

    var locations = [] ;
    $('#selectCity').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf('City') === -1) {
        locations = cityData.filter( c => c.cityName === $(this).val(),)[0].data;
            var locationString = '';
            var locationString2 = '';

            if(locations.length == 0){
              $('#showTimings').html('No shows available');
            }

            $.each(locations, function(i, item) {
                locationString +='<option value="' +item.theaterName +'">' +item.theaterName +'</option>';
                locationString2 +='<option value="' +item.movieName +'">' +item.movieName +'</option>';

                $('#showTimings').html('');
                $.each(locations[i].showTImings,function(i,v){
                  var button = $('<button />').html(v);
                  $('#showTimings').append(button);
                });
            });
            $('#secondselectbox').html(locationString);
            $('#thirdselectbox').html(locationString2);
            $('span#selectedMovie').text($('#thirdselectbox').val());
            $('span#selectedTheater').text($('#secondselectbox').val());


        }
    });

    $('#secondselectbox').on('change', function() {
        var theater = $(this).val();
        for(var i in locations){
            if(locations[i].theaterName===theater){
                $('span#selectedTheater').text(theater);
                $('span#selectedMovie').text(locations[i].movieName);
                $('#thirdselectbox').val(locations[i].movieName);

                $('#showTimings').html('');
                $.each(locations[i].showTImings,function(i,v){
                  var button = $('<button />').html(v);
                  $('#showTimings').append(button);
                });
            }
        }


    });

    $('#thirdselectbox').on('change', function() {
        var movie = $(this).val();
        for(var i in locations){
            if(locations[i].movieName===movie){
                $('span#selectedMovie').text(movie);
                $('span#selectedTheater').text(locations[i].theaterName);
                $('#secondselectbox').val(locations[i].theaterName);

                $('#showTimings').html('');
                $.each(locations[i].showTImings,function(i,v){
                  var button = $('<button />').html(v);
                  $('#showTimings').append(button);
                });



            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
   <div class="UserData">
            <h1><a href="moviebooking.html">MyMovie-Ticket-Booking</a></h1>
            <select class="selectCity" id="selectCity">
                <option value="">Select City</option>
                <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
                <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
                <option value="Guntur">Guntur</option>
                <option value="Ongole">Ongole</option>
            </select>
            <span id="welcome"> </span>
            <p id="demo" class="cityName"></p>
        </div>
         <div class="MoviesList" id="List">
            <label class="TitleName">Movie Name:</label>
            <select id="thirdselectbox" class="TheaterList">
                 <option selected="selected"> Select Movie </option>
            </select>
            <label class="TitleName">Theater Name:</label>
            <select id="secondselectbox" class="MovieList">
                 <option selected="selected"> Select Theater </option>
            </select>
          <fieldset class="Container">
            <legend class="selection">Your Selection</legend>
            <div class="TmName">
                Theater: <span id="selectedTheater"></span>
                <div id="showTimings" style="width: 30%;margin: 0 auto;">
                    <!--<button class="movieTimings"></button>
     <button class="movieTimings"></button>
     <button class="movieTimings"></button>
     <button class="movieTimings"></button>-->
                </div>
                Movie: <span id="selectedMovie"></span>
            </div>
         </fieldset>
        </div>
```

Comment: the question was not clear

Comment: @ whoami when user select the movie in movies dropdown to print the movie name and  list of theaters as well as theater select

Comment: @Babu You need to iterate the `citydata` object and find the theatres and show times

Comment: @Nir Tzezana Can you please tell me how to do that one

Comment: Your code works pretty fine!!! see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ Am I mistaken what you are looking for?

Comment: its working fine but i want one change when select movie in movies dropdown print the movie name and theaters list and at a time don't change the theater drop down (only show the select theater) as well as movie drop down@ Masoud Keshavarz

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cityData = [
        {
            cityName: 'Bengaluru',
            value: 'Bengaluru',
            data: [
                {
                    movieName: 'ABC',
                    theaterName: 'Tulsi Theatre',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'DEF',
                    theaterName: 'PVR',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'GHI',
                    theaterName: 'Srinivasa Theatre',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            cityName: 'Hyderabad',
            value: 'Hyderabad',
            data: [
                {
                    movieName: '123',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre1',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: '456',
                    theaterName: 'PVR2',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: '789',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre3',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
            ],
        },

        {
            cityName: 'Guntur',
            value: 'Guntur',
            data: [
                {
                    movieName: 'ABC1',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre4',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'DEF2',
                    theaterName: 'PVR3',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'GHI3',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre5',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
            ],
        },

        {
            cityName: 'Ongole',
            value: 'Ongole',
            data: [],
        },
    ];

    var locations = [] ;
    $('#selectCity').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf('City') === -1) {
        locations = cityData.filter( c => c.cityName === $(this).val(),)[0].data;
            var locationString = '';
            var locationString2 = '';

            if(locations.length == 0){
              $('#showTimings').html('No shows available');
            }

            $.each(locations, function(i, item) {
                locationString +='<option value="' +item.theaterName +'">' +item.theaterName +'</option>';
                locationString2 +='<option value="' +item.movieName +'">' +item.movieName +'</option>';

                $('#showTimings').html('');
                $.each(locations[i].showTImings,function(i,v){
                  var button = $('<button />').html(v);
                  $('#showTimings').append(button);
                });
            });
            $('#secondselectbox').html(locationString);
            $('#thirdselectbox').html(locationString2);
            $('span#selectedMovie').text($('#thirdselectbox').val());
            $('span#selectedTheater').text($('#secondselectbox').val());


        }
    });

    $('#secondselectbox').on('change', function() {
        var theater = $(this).val();
        for(var i in locations){
            if(locations[i].theaterName===theater){
                $('span#selectedTheater').text(theater);
                $('span#selectedMovie').text(locations[i].movieName);
                $('#thirdselectbox').val(locations[i].movieName);

                $('#showTimings').html('');
                $.each(locations[i].showTImings,function(i,v){
                  var button = $('<button />').html(v);
                  $('#showTimings').append(button);
                });
            }
        }


    });

    $('#thirdselectbox').on('change', function() {
        var movie = $(this).val();
        for(var i in locations){
            if(locations[i].movieName===movie){
                $('span#selectedMovie').text(movie);
                $('span#selectedTheater').text(locations[i].theaterName);
                $('#secondselectbox').val(locations[i].theaterName);

                $('#showTimings').html('');
                $.each(locations[i].showTImings,function(i,v){
                  var button = $('<button />').html(v);
                  $('#showTimings').append(button);
                });



            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="UserData">
            <h1><a href="moviebooking.html">MyMovie-Ticket-Booking</a></h1>
            <select class="selectCity" id="selectCity">
                <option value="">Select City</option>
                <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
                <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
                <option value="Guntur">Guntur</option>
                <option value="Ongole">Ongole</option>
            </select>
            <span id="welcome"> </span>
            <p id="demo" class="cityName"></p>
        </div>
         <div class="MoviesList" id="List">
            <label class="TitleName">Movie Name:</label>
            <select id="thirdselectbox" class="TheaterList">
                 <option selected="selected"> Select Movie </option>
            </select>
            <label class="TitleName">Theater Name:</label>
            <select id="secondselectbox" class="MovieList">
                 <option selected="selected"> Select Theater </option>
            </select>
          <fieldset class="Container">
            <legend class="selection">Your Selection</legend>
            <div class="TmName">
                Theater: <span id="selectedTheater"></span>
                <div id="showTimings" style="width: 30%;margin: 0 auto;">
                    <!--<button class="movieTimings"></button>
     <button class="movieTimings"></button>
     <button class="movieTimings"></button>
     <button class="movieTimings"></button>-->
                </div>
                Movie: <span id="selectedMovie"></span>
            </div>
         </fieldset>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer as well.

Comment: select one drop down another drop down don't change(when user select the movie drop down the theater drop down is default state as well as another )@Dhruvin